# Getting a double free where only one free function is writtern

Tags: c, cs50

my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *name = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    if(!name)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation problem.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    name = get_string("Enter your name: ");

    printf("Hello, %s\n", name);


    free(name);
}
```

output:

```
Enter your name: dog
Hello, dog
*** Error in `malloc0': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001084050 ***
```

I am unable to understand where I am wrong this is a very simple code to take in name an print it but the name stored in heap memory. 
I am just executing `free()` only once but why double free error??

somebody please help me understand the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be better suited on [cs50.se].

Comment: You're discarding the pointer that `malloc` returns.  (1) You call `malloc` and assign the result to `name` (2) You call `get_string` and assign that result to `name`, losing the old poiinter (3) you try to free whatever `get_string` returned, which presumably didn't come from `malloc`.

Comment: @Ctx - This question *is* about the workings of cs50, for which an entire SE site exists and where questions about should be directed. It very much *is* appropriate.

Comment: @StoryTeller The question might be on-topic there, too (perhaps it fits even better), but it is _definitively not_ off-topic here!

Comment: @Ctx - Then don't vote in favor. I'll vote as I see fit, whether you agree or not.

Comment: @Ctx - Only if you take it there.

Answer (score 4):

cs50 automagically manages its own memory.

Before main the libcs50 registers `atexit` callback in [cs.50:449](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c#L449):

```
/**
 * Called automatically before execution enters main.
 */
INITIALIZER(setup)
{
    // Disable buffering for standard output
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    atexit(teardown);
}
```

The `teardown()` function deallocates all the memory allocated by libcs50:

```
static void teardown(void)
{
    // Free library's strings
    if (strings != NULL)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < allocations; i++)
        {
            free(strings[i]);
        }
        free(strings);
    }
}
```

Where `strings` is a global object in [cs50.c:67](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c#L67).

When you `free(name)` the pointer behind the name is also stored in `strings[0]` (assigned [in `get_string()`](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c#L205)).

After `main()` exits, the `atexit` registered callback are executed, and `free(strings[0])` is executed which tries to double free the object.

Answer (score 3):

From the description of get_string:

Prompts user for a line of text from standard input and returns it as a string (char *), sans trailing line ending. Supports CR (\r), LF (\n), and CRLF (\r\n) as line endings. Stores string on heap,*but library's destructor frees memory on program's exit*. The prompt is formatted like printf(3).

so as you can see it also frees it from heap at exit.